# IReport .jrxml font url to parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

Basically, I want to change the font name URL from the parameters.

I tried to do it like $P{FONT_PATH} inside the url.

```
<paramter name="FONT_PATH" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <testElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
      <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" size="8" isBold="false" pdfFontName="/resources/fonts/ARIALUNI.TFF"/>
    </testElement>
```

Comment: It does not work like this - you should use font extensions

Comment: @AlexK  I cannot use font extensions now, it is a legacy code. so I need to use it this way.